# Showing/Hiding fields in form on result of drop down menu

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am building a form that takes data a query on three access separate tables.

The problem I have it that my previous version of the for had too many fields and thus was confusing for the end user. I have a drop down menu with four distinct options. Those are the only four that can be chosen (so as to prevent random data entry) and depending on which gets selected, I want to have some fields show and other not, since they would not be relevant to it. I'm also wanting this to work when a user browses through the records of the form (i.e.: the fields show/hide depending on the value in the drop down menu).

I've tried to use the following code (I'm a complete beginner in VBA):

```
Private Sub Status_Change()
    If Status.Value = "Blue" Then
        Me.Field_1.Visible = False
        Me.Field_2.Visible = False
        Me.Field_3.Visible = False
        Me.Field_4.Visible = False
        Me.Field_5.Visible = False
        Me.Field_6.Visible = False
        Me.Field_7.Visible = False
    Else
    If Status.Value = "Green" Then
        Me.Field_1.Visible = True
        Me.Field_2.Visible = False
        Me.Field_3.Visible = False
        Me.Field_4.Visible = False
        Me.Field_5.Visible = False
        Me.Field_6.Visible = True
        Me.Field_7.Visible = True
    Else
    If Status.Value = "Red" Then
        Me.Field_1.Visible = True
        Me.Field_2.Visible = False
        Me.Field_3.Visible = False
        Me.Field_4.Visible = False
        Me.Field_5.Visible = False
        Me.Field_6.Visible = True
        Me.Field_7.Visible = True
    Else
    If Status.Value = "Yellow" Then
        Me.Field_1.Visible = True
        Me.Field_2.Visible = True
        Me.Field_3.Visible = True
        Me.Field_4.Visible = True
        Me.Field_5.Visible = True
        Me.Field_6.Visible = False
        Me.Field_7.Visible = True
    Else
    If Status.Value = "Orange" Then
        Me.Field_1.Visible = True
        Me.Field_2.Visible = False
        Me.Field_3.Visible = False
        Me.Field_4.Visible = False
        Me.Field_5.Visible = False
        Me.Field_6.Visible = False
        Me.Field_7.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

So far it has not worked and I am not really sure on what I am doing wrong. Is anyone able to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The fields stay visible, no matter what the "Status" value shows when browsing through the records or inputting a new record. There are no errors given.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get errors? Explain what "it has not work".

Comment: The fields stay visible, no matter what the "Status" value shows when browsing through the records or inputting a new record. There are no errors given.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `AfterUpdate` event rather than the `OnChange` event.

Assuming `Status` is a combobox, you may want to check that the **bound column** of the combobox holds the values you are testing for.

Note that your code could be reduced to the following:

```
Private Sub Status_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Field_1.Visible = Status <> "Blue"
    Me.Field_2.Visible = Status = "Yellow"
    Me.Field_3.Visible = Status = "Yellow"
    Me.Field_4.Visible = Status = "Yellow"
    Me.Field_5.Visible = Status = "Yellow"
    Me.Field_6.Visible = Status = "Green" or Status = "Red"
    Me.Field_7.Visible = Status <> "Blue"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. The 'Status' value comes from on of the access tables (column with the same name) and is a drop down menu with four options. I'm going to try with the 'AfterUpdate' event. I knew that my code was way too long... >.>

Comment: Alright, I have checked and the combobox's properties are as follows: "Row Source" contains the four possible values, "Row Source Type" is listed as "Value List", and "Bound Column" is 1. I have tested the code (Which I agree is much better than what I had) but the fields still stay visible, no matter what the "Status" value is.

Comment: If the Bound Column is 1, does column 1 (the first column) in the Row Source contain the values we are testing? (e.g. `Blue`, `Yellow` etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is actually a drop down menu there which has the five values (made a mistake in the comment above, it is five values, not four) that can be selected. The table this is contained in has that drop down menu for each cell of that "Status" column so it can be chosen when a new record is made or a current one updated.

Comment: I'm still stumped on this. Not sure what I'm doing wrong that is causing the fields to remain visible despite the status field value. I did notice that I cannot add any data in the form when it is in form view (edit fields or even add a new record). I checked the properties-data tab and edits are allowed. I'm starting to think that this is being caused due to me basing this form from a query result on the three tables I use in my database.